# Datatables multi-select Dropdown Filter Update on filter change

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables 1.10

When i select a filter in my Datatable , I am trying to update my filters as per the result set which is generated.

Here is my code.

```
table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "bSort": false,
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        $("#example thead td ").each(function (i) {
            if (i > 1) {
                select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(this).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        table.column(i)
                            .search($(this).val())
                            .draw();
                    });
            }

            table.column(i).data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                if (i > 1 && d !== "") {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

What i am trying to do in above code is to add dropdown filter code in the callback of datatable function.

So that when each time the datatable runs i should get the new filters.

Is there any option in datatable to do this?

Comment: Your last line of code is incomplete. Please fix it / delete it / add the rest.

Comment: Actually i was trying to give a function call through that sorry i am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using DT 1.9 API on DT v 1.10
Please refer to the newer version of DT http://www.datatables.net/reference/

If I understand you correctly, you want to change neighboor filters (mark "no-data" options grey for example) when any other filter got applied. If this is correct, stick to 
[`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)

The logic you use in your code seems to be close to how this is tackled, I don't know of any DT supported ways on creating combo-box column filters and of updating them, so yes, every time it draws, check the filter, and update/recreate the combos.

If you are not chasing for DT 1.10, [here is working plugin](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColumnFilterWidgets/DataTables/extras/ColumnFilterWidgets/) for DT 1.9 by Dylan Kuhn.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and great response, DT1.9 plugin is awesome, just one small thing i will need from it is , how to place those filters below headers in datatables? Also how to place the selected filter value above table?

Comment: If you'd like to place the combos right into the header cells, I'm afraid you'll have to change the plugin code https://github.com/cyberhobo/ColumnFilterWidgets, or add a hacky JQ run-through of each table header cell with pushing inside of it corresponding combobox. Author of the plugin mentions that this being a Widget is located in a separete element. If you decide to change plugin source code, my quess is line 115 is the place responsible for combos placement https://github.com/cyberhobo/ColumnFilterWidgets/blob/master/media/js/ColumnFilterWidgets.js. Btw, upvote gives reputation ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information, It was vary helpful. One more question i am looking for reset button for filter reset is there any option in ColumnFilterWidgets for that?

Comment: No, don't think this is possible with this plugin. You can see how individual selection removal works at lines 193 - 210. But I don't think adding clear option would be easy, you'll need to add it in wrapper object - ColumnFilterWidgets, than run through .aoWidgets and clear each column combo and than do table.fnFilter.

Comment: Hi, need help on Reset filters here are the links [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034076/jquery-datatables-and-columnfilterwidget-reset-all-filters-button) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080959/jquery-datatables-and-columnfilterwidget-reset-filter-issue)

Comment: This one seems tough, I've commented in the -link1- suggesting you to create a test-case at http://jsfiddle.net/